# How to apply a rolling Kalman Filter to a column in a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, kalman-filter

How to apply a rolling Kalman Filter to a DataFrame column (without using external data)?

That is, pretending that each row is a new point in time and therefore requires for the descriptive statistics to be updated (in a rolling manner) after each row.

For example, how to apply the Kalman Filter to any column in the below DataFrame?

```
n = 2000
index = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', periods=n)
data = np.random.randn(n, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('ABCD'), index=index)
```

I've seen previous responses ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599886/kalman-filter-with-varying-timesteps) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944512/how-to-apply-kalman-filter-models-to-fit-a-signal-in-python)) however they are not applying it to a DataFrame column (and they are not vectorized).

How to apply a rolling Kalman Filter to a column in a DataFrame?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out how to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exploiting some good features of `numpy` and using `pykalman` library, and applying the Kalman Filter on column D for a rolling window of 3, we can write:

```
import pandas as pd
from pykalman import KalmanFilter
import numpy as np

def rolling_window(a, step):
    shape   = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - step + 1, step)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def get_kf_value(y_values):
    kf = KalmanFilter()
    Kc, Ke = kf.em(y_values, n_iter=1).smooth(0)
    return Kc

n = 2000
index = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', periods=n)
data = np.random.randn(n, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('ABCD'), index=index)

wsize = 3
arr = rolling_window(df.D.values, wsize)
zero_padding = np.zeros(shape=(wsize-1,wsize))
arrst = np.concatenate((zero_padding, arr))
arrkalman = np.zeros(shape=(len(arrst),1))

for i in range(len(arrst)):
    arrkalman[i] = get_kf_value(arrst[i])

kalmandf = pd.DataFrame(arrkalman, columns=['D_kalman'], index=index)
df = pd.concat([df,kalmandf], axis=1)
```

`df.head()` should yield something like this:

```
                   A         B         C         D  D_kalman
2000-01-01 -0.003156 -1.487031 -1.755621 -0.101233  0.000000
2000-01-02  0.172688 -0.767011 -0.965404 -0.131504  0.000000
2000-01-03 -0.025983 -0.388501 -0.904286  1.062163  0.013633
2000-01-04 -0.846606 -0.576383 -1.066489 -0.041979  0.068792
2000-01-05 -1.505048  0.498062  0.619800  0.012850  0.252550
```

Comment: Thanks! How could the above example be extended from 3 periods to 10 as an example? Tried doing this and had issues.

Comment: I edited the example to include a window size variable `wsize` so if you put `wsize = 10`, you should get the desired result @Greg .

Comment: Is there any way to make the kalman filter 'stronger', i.e. smoothen more? What additional parameters can I set?

Comment: There is a smoothing parameter in pykalman and all parameters are explained in their document: https://pykalman.github.io/
Also another way to smoothen is to use longer window sizes. @Nickpick